# Django не импортируеться aplication, как запустить фаил?

Tags: python, django

запускаю Фаил  так

aster3/telping# python3 demonik.py

сам фаил

```
import asterisk.manager
import re
import time
import os
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "aster3.settings"
import django
django.setup()
from telping.models import Tellping_offline, Tellping_online
import datetime


def sbor24():
    a=1
    while a < 5:
    .........
```

ошибка такая

```
root@xmaster-HP-ProBook-4540s:/home/xmaster/PycharmProjects/aster3/telping# python3 demonik.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demonik.py", line 7, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'aster3'
```

А в Pytcharm работает, собственно вопрос как подцепить aplication из django ?
Чтоб всё заработало.
структура
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Без представления о полной структуре проекта утверждать наверняка сложно, но скорее всего проблема в области видимости. demonik.py запускается из каталога модуля telping, в области имен которого нет aster3. Попробуйте:

```
root@xmaster-HP-ProBook-4540s:/home/xmaster/PycharmProjects/aster3# python3 telping/./demonik.py
```